# Do git hooks (pre-commit, post-commit, etc) apply to all branches?

Tags: git

So, they do, I checked.

How do I get them to only run on certain branches? Or am I bonkers for wanting that?

I'm not working on a specific project at the moment. I'm exploring static site generators, hosting on AWS S3, and learning about potential workflows for this paradigm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like `git rev-parse --symbolic --branches` in your hook script to determine what branch you are on and adjust your logic accordingly.

It does seem to be a rather odd requirement, though. Perhaps if you described the requirements you're trying to address, there might be alternative approaches...

Comment: Yes, let me update the question. I'm not working on a specific project, just learning about static site generators and AWS S3 hosting and such.